# Rails 4 alternate primary key with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a strange problem I just cannot figure out.

I want to use the clustering ability of mysql to store related records beside each other on disk. Mysql clusters by the primary key on the table, which for a default rails model is ID.

However, for a lot of tables, it may make sense for the primary key of the table to be, for example, user_id, subscription_id, clustering the related records beside each, and making for a very efficient lookup when you ask the database for all of a user's subscriptions.

To do this, I created a mysql table like:

```
 execute('create table subscriptions (
             id         integer not null auto_increment,
             user_id    integer not null,
             feed_id    integer not null,
             folder_id  integer,
             created_at     datetime,
             updated_at     datetime,
             primary key (user_id, feed_id),
             key id (id)
          ) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8');
```

Notice that my PK is user_id, feed_id but I still have the ID column present, and I want rails to still use that as what it believes is the PK for the table.

First off, this didn't work at all until I set:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = 'id'
  ...
end
```

Now comes the strange part.

When I run my tests, I get a strange error:

```
Mysql::Error: Field 'id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `subscriptions`
```

However - if I stick the application in development mode and do operations through the webpage, it works just fine.

After a lot of googling, I found a monkey patch to stop Rails setting MySQL into a stricter mode:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter

private
  alias_method :configure_connection_without_strict_mode, :configure_connection

  def configure_connection
    configure_connection_without_strict_mode
    strict_mode = "SQL_MODE=''"
    execute("SET #{strict_mode}", :skip_logging)
  end
end
```

If I add this, my test suit appears to work (for most tests, but not all), but any models that get created have an ID of zero.

Again in production mode, through the webpage things work just fine, and the models get an auto_increment ID as expected.

Has anyone got any ideas on what I can do this make my test suite work correctly in this setup?

Comment: Wouldn't using a UUID primary key be more reliable than this?

Comment: Not sure about a UUID PK. Its really just another surrogate PK similar to an ID sequence. I don't really want to start a discussion about MySQL clustering, but by having the PK on user_id, feed_id, it means that even when users create feeds over a long period of time, they will all be stored beside each other on disk, allowing all of them to be read with a single DB read or two, instead of many. Its also the natural key on the table, as the table should be unique on that pair.

Comment: Why not throw a unique constraint/index on the `(user_id,feed_id)` pair and leave the PK alone? That would probably be easier with Rails than trying to mess around with the PK.

Comment: The unique index of user_id, feed_id will get the job done, but with reduced performance (which why I am trying this out). It doesn't solve the mystery around why my app works in server mode, but not via the test suite :-/

Comment: @StephenODonnell why will this reduce performance?

Comment: @namphibian - See http://www.joehruska.com/?p=6 and http://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/07/15/rails-mysql-and-clustered-primary-keys/ for two good posts about how MySQL can cluster related data and what that can mean in terms of disk reads.

Comment: @StephenODonnell this is a very well understood concept and not a performance killer. Reading the entire table will be a performance killer. I answered a question about it here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18528/performance-difference-between-clustered-and-non-clustered-index/18531#18531 which explains   the whole thing a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is going on.

What I did not remember, is that the development database is created by running migrations against the database, which also generates the schema.rb file. The schema.rb file is then used to load the test database.

So while my development database looked as I expected, the test database looked different - it would seem that the code which generates the schema.rb file cannot understand the database format I created and does not create a schema.rb that reflects my migrations correctly.

If I load my test database with:

```
$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

And then run my test suite with:

```
$ rake test:all
```

Things work correctly. This is because the test:all task does not reload the database before running the test suite.

So what I described in the question to create an alternative primary key while maintaining the rails ID key works, except for the schema.rb part.